# Django queryset count with extra select

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a model with PointField for location coordinates. I have a MySQL function that calculates the distance between two points called **dist**. I use extra() "select" to calculate distance for each returned object in the queryset. I also use extra() "where" to filter those objects that are within a specific range. Like this

```
query = queryset.extra(
    select={
        "distance":"dist(geomfromtext('%s'),geomfromtext('%s'))"%(loc1, loc2)
    },
    where=["1 having `distance` <= %s"%(km)]
) #simplified example
```

This works fine for getting and reading the results, except when I try counting the resultset I get the error that **'distance' is not a field**. After exploring a bit further, it seems that count ignores the "select" from extra and just uses "where". While the full SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT (dist(geomfromtext('POINT (-4.6858300000000003 36.5154300000000021)'),geomfromtext('POINT (-4.8858300000000003 36.5154300000000021)'))) AS `distance`, `testmodel`.`id`, `testmodel`.`name`, `testmodel`.`email`, (...) FROM `testmodel` WHERE 1 having `distance` <= 50.0
```

The count query is much shorter and doesn't have the dist selection part:

```
SELECT COUNT( `testmodel`.`id`) FROM `testmodel` WHERE 1 having `distance` <= 50.0
```

Logically, MySQL gives an error because "distance" is undefined. Is there a way to tell Django it has to include the extra select for the count?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: do you need to stick with mysql? or can you use another RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) if you are not plannig to use any other database system.

```
    params = {'point1':wktpoint1, 'point2':wktpoint2}
    query = """
        SELECT
            dist(%(point1)s, %(point2)s)
        FROM
            testmodel
    ;"""
    query_set = self.raw(query, params)
```

Also, if you need more GIS support, you should evaluate PostgreSQL+[PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) (If you don't like to reinvent the wheel, you should not make your own dist function)

Django offers GIS support through GeoDjango. There you got functions like [distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lookups). You should check support [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#compatibility-tables)

In order to use GeoDjango you need to add a field on yout model, to tell them to use the [GeoManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geomanager), Then you can start doing geoqueries, and you should have no problems with `count`.

with mysql you cando something like this using geodjango

```
### models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class YourModel(models.Model):
    your_geo_field=models.PolygonField()
    #your_geo_field=models.PointField()
    #your_geo_field=models.GeometryField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

### your code
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
a_geom=fromstr('POINT(-96.876369 29.905320)', srid=4326)
distance=5
YoourModel.objects.filter(your_geo_field__distance_lt=(a_geom, D(m=distance))).count()
```

you can see better examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries) and the reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lookups)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot use PostgreSQL because we are limited to Amazon RDS, which runs MySQL. I could use raw sql. But how do I do COUNT() putting dist() result as condition? I need to count only results, which distance is within a certain range.

Comment: MySQL have basic GIS support, have you tried geodjango? you can do this: `YoourModel.objects.filter(your_geo_field__distance_lt=(a_geom, D(m=5))).count()`

Comment: Also, try NOT using an alias for the distance select dist function.
In a raw query you should filter using the function (dist) with parameters in the where clause, then count(*) in the select clause.